# Inside the PnP Modern Search Result web part what is the differecne beween Query Text and Refinement filters

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, query, refiner, pnp-search-webparts

I added the PnP Modern Search web part from this link @ https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/releases . and inside the "PnP - Search Results"web part, i have 2 sections; Query Text & Refinement filters, as follow:-

[image]

So what is the difference between these 2 options? and when to use each?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, there is generally no difference between Query text and Refinement filters. But Refinement filters only supports to Refinable Managed Properties.

**Here is a good Blog for you to read:**

- [How to create a Managed Property in SharePoint Online](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-a-managed-property-in-sharepoint-online/)

---

Reference:

[What is the difference between Query text and Refinement filters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/640137/what-is-the-difference-between-query-text-and-refi.html)

Answer (score 0):

The big difference between two is based on it's data source and *ability to utilize **Tokens** for dynamic queries*.

Note that in SharePoint (as data source), you can use both. However, in Microsoft Search (Graph API), only Query template field is allowed.

**Additional info see [here](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-results/tokens/#date-tokens)**